# UIButton custom attributed font NSRange iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, nsattributedstring

Im trying to make a custom font using attributed string for custom `UIButton` in `xcode` using `swift 2.0`

However it works fine in interface builder but not working in any device or simulator, I'm using `xcode 7.3` latest with ios 9.3 but unfortunately it seems a bug in `xcode/ios`. After searching it from google, I came to realize that its should be treat programatically with swift.

My goal is to just put custom font with `NSRange` such that I have attributed string of `ABCDEF` with new line after each alphabet. And I just need to setup the Custom font for first two elements via `swift`. Below is the example

```
A    <---  font1
B    <---  fontMiddle
CDEF <---  font1
```

**P.S: I need exact font size and color which is set in interface builder and just want to set the custom readable font for swift**

Here's my try:

```
let size = (tryButton?.titleLabel?.font?.pointSize)!

let labelFont = UIFont(name: "font1", size: size)

let middleFont = UIFont(name: "fontMiddle", size: size)



let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:(tryButton.titleLabel?.text)!)

attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: labelFont!, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 1) )

attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: middleFont!, range: NSRange(location: 1, length: 2) )

attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: labelFont!, range: NSRange(location: 2, length: attributedString.lenght) )

tryButton.setAttributedTitle(attributedString, forState: .Normal)
```

Comment: 1. Have you added you custom fonts in `.plist` file of your project?
2. When you debug your code, do you see that `labelFont` and `middleFont` are initialized properly

Comment: 3. There's a small bug in your code.

It should be `attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: middleFont!, range: NSRange(location: 1, length: 1) )`

Comment: @noir_eagle yes yes, I have added and they are working fine in whole app even in interface builder also .. but not in attributed strings basically.

Comment: @noir_eagle secondly I need stroyboard settings like font size etc, how can I achieve that for each element

Comment: `NSRange(location: 2, length: attributedString.lenght)` Should cause a crash, no? `NSRange(location: 2, length: attributedString.lenght-2)` instead?

Comment: @Larme yes that should .. can you please answer this in editing the code to set custom font with existing font sizes

Comment: Could you log `attributedString` at the end?